# Is there any cache in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

**General concept of app:** From the admin panel I want to be able to do CRUD operations on following entities: ***Slider*** and ***Banner***. ***Banner*** can be added to many ***Sliders*** and can have different **position** on each. Due to that fact there is a third entity: ***BannerSlider*** that consists of *banner_id*, *slider_id* and *position* fields;

---

**Code:**

```
export const SliderEdit = props => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <NumberInput source="status" />
            <ArrayInput source="bannerSliders">
                <SimpleFormIterator>
                    <ReferenceInput label="Banner" source="banner.id" reference="banners">
                        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
                    </ReferenceInput>

                    <NumberInput source="position" />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

---

**Issue:** When there are 5 banners assigned to given slider, there are 5 requests to backend, each from `<ReferenceInput>`. Each request is the same request and have same parameters. Is there any way to call the backend only once? Or maybe there is something wrong with my code?

---

Also, as a side note - I think when user clicks "add" there shouldn't be additional request for the new `ReferenceInput`, cause all the data is already there. But that's something to consider for the authors. ( Yeah, I know I may contribute too :P )

Comment: This is weird, we actually did some optimizations for that very use case: we catch every calls for data from the ReferenceInput and merge them in a single request. What version and what dataProvider are you using ?

Comment: Hi, @GildasGarcia, ra-data-json-server: 2.7.0  and react-admin 2.7.1